# Identify column names from DataFrame in Python when Column names are unknown

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I run a for loop for executing few SQL queries . I have the results captured in a DataFrame (again inside the loop) as below for two validations.

DATAFRAME for Test1:

```
index  column1     column2   
0    jack          100   
1    bill          200   
2    Tom           300
```

DATAFRAME Looks for Test2:

```
index  column1    
0    102345    
1    102345
```

I have to write the results of Dataframe for each Test to another table in Oracle  . In order to do this , I need to get the column names. I am unable to Identify how many column names are present at a given point in time in the loop as the Dataframe can have from 1-5 columns depending upon the SQL run . Is there a way to do this .

Code for reading from table and writing to DataFrame:

```
def get_src_query_metadata(cursor, sql_query):

   cursor.execute(sql_query)
   columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
   cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip(columns, args))
   data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
   return data

def get_target_query_metadata(cursor, sql_query):

   cursor.execute(sql_query)
   columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
   cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip(columns, args))
   data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
   return data
              
def main():
   
           _JobDict_src = get_src_query_metadata(cursor, src_query[i])
           _JobDict_tgt = get_target_query_metadata(cursor, target_query[i])
```

How do I get the column names and its values assign to  separate variables .

Answer (score 0):

You can find and count column names through this loop

```
coln=0
for col in df.columns:
    coln+=1
    print(col)

print(coln)
```

and find data types through the following

```
for col in df.dtypes:
    print(col)
```